# Create new user from angular to Keycloack

Tags: angular, keycloak

i want as an admin role to create many clients from my angular form interface and store them inside Keycloak with their roles , with Rest API Post if it possible,how can i do this ?

**Thanks**

Comment: Have a look at https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_response